# WebApi 2 Controller Creation Fails ONLY ONCE A WEEK in Production

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api2

We have a web api 2 service. I am using Unity for dependency injection and Entityframework for ORM. I register classes separately in Unity as in the code section below. Every week, I am getting this error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'CashAccountFlowController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   Type 'Analytical.Controller.CashAccountFlowController' does not have a
>   default constructor    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type
>   type)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

Till last week, I was getting this error every Monday. Every Sunday night we do iisreset. But this week I got this error on Tuesday. All the rest of the days it works fine. This service is not used in weekends.

My controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CashAccountContract cashAccountContract)

public CashAccountFlowController(IAnalyticalInformationService analyticalInformationService,
        IDtoDomainMapper dtoDomainMapper) : base(dtoDomainMapper)
    {
        _analyticalInformationService = analyticalInformationService;
    }
```

The flow service in-turn refers to the UnitOfWork, then UnitOfWork refers the repositories.

Unity Dependency Injection Registration.

```
    private void Register()
    {


 //Register Repositories

_unityContainer.RegisterType<IEntityDomainMapper, EntityDomainMapper>();
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<AnalyticalServiceEntities, AnalyticalServiceEntities>();
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<DbContext, AnalyticalServiceEntities>();
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IConversationRepository, ConversationRepository>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IAnalyticalRepository, AnalyticalRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IBoxRepository, BoxRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<ICashAccountSeriLogRepository, CashAccountSeriLogRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());   



 //Register Services

_unityContainer.RegisterType<IAnalyticalInformationService, AnalyticalInformationService>(
         new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IAnalyticalDataOutstandingService, AnalyticalDataOutstandingService>(
         new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IAnalyticalIntradayService, AnalyticalIntradayService>(
         new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(
         new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());   



 //Register Controllers

        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IDtoDomainMapper, DtoDomainMapper>();
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<ICashAccountFlowController, CashAccountFlowController>();

    }
```

Earlier, I tried HierarchicalLifeTimeManager as well as transient (as above) but none didn't help me.

I am not able to reproduce it locally.
Could you please help me why it is failing `ONLY ONCE` a week in Production.

Thanks in advance,

Pandiarajan.

Answer (score 1):

Some one of your constructors is doing more than it should and is causing an error when its parent type is being resolved.

You need to review the dependencies of the suspect controller `CashAccountFlowController` and verify that its object graph is being resolved completely without errors.

That standard error message is returned when the framework is unable to properly initialize a controller through a constructor that has dependencies that it cannot safely provide.

SO check to make sure that the constructors of the objects in the graph are not performing logic that can cause errors that happen on the days in question.

Comment: Hi NKosi,                                                                                                   
             1. This is a typical scenario for any application, Controller=> Service Layer  => Repository => EntityFramework DB Context.  So, when the controller is initialized all the dependencies are loaded. Could you please help me what should I do to avoid this problem.                    
  2. Could you please suggest some tools to review and verify the object graph is completely resolved without errors?